# How to get help of job_spec and (( )) in bash?

Tags: bash

To get help of bash builtins, just type `help ...`, for example, `help [[` returns the help of `[[ ... ]]`, but it doesn't work for `job_spec` and `(( ... ))`

Comment: the word `job_spec` doesn't appear in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html). `help '(('` and `help \(\(` both work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `job_spec` help, enter `help %`;
For `(( expression ))` help, enter `help '(('`.

Answer (score 0):

Only place that refers `jobspec` is chapter [`7.2 Job Control Builtins`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html)
 of `Bash Reference Manual`. `jobspec` is just identifier of job. 
For example when I stop `emacs` and `htop` I'm getting the following output (first column is `jobspec`):

```
[1]+  Stopped                 emacs -nw
[2]+  Stopped                 htop
```

Now I can bring `emacs` to foreground by using its `jobspec`: `fg 1`.

In `man jobs` this is also called `job id`.

Comment: 7.1 actually gives the definition, seems more useful than 7.2. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html#Job-Control-Basics